# libgdx boilerplate code fails to work

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx

I've downloaded the latest version of libgdx 1.0.1 (I used to have 0.9.8) and the core code as generated by the version 3 setup/project creation wizard is completely different - it does not dispose of the batch or the texture, there is no camera or positioning set up and when I run it the loaded images are not displayed in the correct place, probably due to the camera not being set up.

If I put back the code from the wizard version 2, everything works.

What's going wrong? here's the code generated by old and new:
Here's the new code:

```
    @Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
    batch.end();
}
```

Here is the old code

```
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture texture;
private Sprite sprite;

@Override
public void create() {      
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h/w);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg"));
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 512, 275);

    sprite = new Sprite(region);
    sprite.setSize(0.9f, 0.9f * sprite.getHeight() / sprite.getWidth());
    sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth()/2, sprite.getHeight()/2);
    sprite.setPosition(-sprite.getWidth()/2, -sprite.getHeight()/2);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    texture.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: "Correct place" is a relative term. I think the boilerplate stuff is only there so you can quickly see if you're up and running. Maybe they decided to streamline it. Yes, without setting up a camera, the dimensions will be different (but not necessarily incorrect, just depends on your dimensioning scheme). I think they should at least be disposing of the Texture and Batch though, because it might be a bad lesson to a newcomer to see that ignored.

Comment: I for one appreciate the changes, because there's less stuff to delete out when I start new projects.

Comment: hmm. so you're saying they probably stripped down the code given this is just a 'hello world' but forgot to clean up and made it so the sample image doesn't get displayed on screen? I only say this because I'm new and there was no explanation in the new wizard download or something useful at the libgdx wiki for this.

Comment: I'm still on 1.0.0. looking at the above boiler plate, it looks to me like you are probably only seeing one pixel of the texture. Try changing `batch.draw(img, 0, 0);` to `batch.draw(img, 0, 0, 0.5f, 0.5f);`. I would then expect to see the texture, stretched to fit the upper right quadrant of the window.